# Adding 'timeout' flag to ffprobe/ffmpeg causes it to fail immediately

Tags: video, ffmpeg, timeout, ffprobe

If I run `ffprobe -timeout 20 -v trace -print_format json -show_format -show_streams 'http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4'`, the command fails immediately with a `Connection timed out` error even though I set the timeout to 20 seconds. It doesn't wait anywhere near 20 seconds, just exits right away with an exit code of 1. Here's the trace output.

```
ffprobe version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.2.1 (GCC) 20160830
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-netcdf --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
{
[http @ 0x5598e7df1e20] Setting default whitelist 'http,https,tls,rtp,tcp,udp,crypto,httpproxy'
[http @ 0x5598e7df1e20] request: GET /video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/57.56.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: www.sample-videos.com
Icy-MetaData: 1


http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4: Connection timed out

}
```

If I remove the `-timeout 20` flag the command works fine. How can I get `ffprobe` to work with timeouts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The unit of `-timeout` are different in each protocol.

In HTTP, the unit is microseconds.

Comment: rtsp timeout doesn't work as it should. setting timeout to any positive value causes a not found message, regardless of whether the rtsp stream is able to be connected to or not.

Comment: I can't find `timeout` in the [http section of the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#http).

Comment: I found the `timeout` option here:
PROTOCOLS: ftp, rtmp, smb, ssh/sftp, rtp, rtsp, srt, tcp, udp, Unix local socket | 
FORMATS: dash, hls

Answer (score 1):

I have resolve the problem for rtsp streaming by adding the option

```
   -stimeout 8000 // in microseconds
```

See documentation for more info http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp